# How can I check the browsing history in Vue / Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on nuxt.js project and want to ask a question. When I display modal using [bootstrap's modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), does it stack the URL to the browser viewing history?
[image]

Here is the detail of the problem I currently have.
I have two pages, which are page A and B.

- Page A has a button to link to page B, and I used $router.replace of [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html). So the history is not supposed to add.
- Page B has a button to show modal, and the modal has a modal close button, which literally closes the modal and back to page B.

The problem is, once I opened and closed the modal, I have to press the browser"s back button twice to back to page A.
like,
show modal on page B -> close modal on page B -> press browsers back button (but the URL doesn't changes and still stays on page B) -> press browsers back button again, and back to page A.

So I thought by showing a modal using bootstrap adds new history entry.

### add this part later

here is a code for modal

```html
// display modal 
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeModal">show modal</button>

// dismiss modal
<div class="mdal fade" id="removeModal">
    <p data-dismiss="modal">
        <img src="@/assets/img/x-icon.png" alt="X-icon">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: Hi there. So sorry for the late reply. I was not able to solve the problem I have, but thanks to your suggestion, I can now see the history of the routing. So it was really helpful. I think there is a bug for displaying modal, and that is why this routing issue happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could confirm this by using: `window.history.length` and track the number:

- before the modal
- during the modal
- after the modal

That way, you will be sure if it's actually Bootstrap. Meanwhile, I doubt this is it (because it is using `vue-portal` and not some shady history API tricks).

I do think that it's coming from somewhere else. Firstly, why do you use `replace` if you actually plan to allow to go back to this page ? Also, why not using `nuxt-link` for the purpose of moving to another page ?

As an alternative, to help you debug, you can use the `Routing - History` tab of your devtools, it will show you exactly what is inserted into vue-router (in case you have a middleware or idk that is pushing 2 entries ?).
[image]

---

EDIT, I tested it myself with a brand new Nuxt project and it's totally working as expected with both of those solutions and a modal on the target page (index)

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'index' }" replace>replace index</nuxt-link>
<button @click="$router.replace({ name: 'index' })">replace to index</button>
```

So, I guess that something is wrong with your code at this point.